# How to find total number of sold products in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

i want to display total sold amount on any page in shopify.
for example : i have 10 products in collection and each is 20$ ,in which 6 are sold.
how to find total amounts of sold products
      total amount = 6*20 =120.

Answer (score 1):

In a vanilla Liquid template, you cannot directly access sales. You would have to know how many you started with. You could do that with a metafield i.e. use it to store your starting total, from which you can deduce how many have been sold by checking the current Variant inventory quantities, then do your price calculation.